# Visual Studio Community 2015 and C Language Debugging

Tags: c, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-debugging

When I debug a C program and press F11, for example, on strcmp instruction, the debugger open a window with strcmp.asm to continue debugging the strcmp instructions in assembler. How can I stop this behavior ?

Comment: What would you expect instead of this behavior?

Comment: Try options->debugging->general and uncheck "Show disassembly if source is not available".  This location is for VS2010 and VS2017.  I don't have a copy of VS2015 to confirm the location.  However, I use the F10 key to single step through source code and F11 to step into functions as described by @Lundin so I rarely have this problem.

Comment: @Eugene, I expect that the debugger goes to the next instruction of my source code, not to debug Microsoft code.

Comment: @thurizas, It doesn't work for me even I uncheck "Show disassembly ...", thanks

Answer (score 1):

F10 = step over functions.
F11 = step into functions.

Press the appropriate button when single-stepping.

Comment: ... and if already inside the assembler code press Shift-F11 to return to the last line of C source before having entered into the mess.